# Не переприсваиваются арибуты через $this php5

Tags: php

Версия PHP Version 5.2.12

**Так работает:**

```
 class MyClass
 {
   var $attribute1;
   var $attribute2;

   function Method1($param1, $param2)
   {
       $attribute1 = $param1;
       $attribute2 = $param2;
       echo "Значение атрибутов 1-ый=$attribute1, 2-ой=$attribute2<br/>";   
   }
 }
```

**При вызове метода obj->Method1(45,67) вывод:** 
    Значение атрибутов 1-ый=45, 2-ой=67

**Так (при использовании $this) нет:**

```
 class MyClass
 {
   var $attribute1;
   var $attribute2;

   function Method1($param1, $param2)
   {
       $this->attribute1 = $param1;
       $this->attribute2 = $param2;
       echo "Значение атрибутов 1-ый=$attribute1, 2-ой=$attribute2<br/>";   
   }
 }
```

**При вызове метода obj->Method1(45,67) вывод:** 
    Значение атрибутов 1-ый=, 2-ой=

В чем может быть причина?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вы же присваиваете `$this->attribute1` так почему же считываете `$attribute1` ?

```
 echo "Значение атрибутов 1-ый={$this->attribute1}, 2-ой={$this->attribute2}<br/>";
```

Comment: только начал учить, спасибо)